# Recursive multiplication in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, recursion

I have a table of widget recipes in Postgres ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74d761/1)). The recipes can span multiple rows and each row represents a component of the recipe. Each recipe can have multiple parts and those parts can have subparts with specific quantity. Finally there are subparts at the end of chain with no other subparts below them.

How can I recursively multiply the quantity of the subparts for a given recipe? For example querying `WHERE part = 'chest'` should return this:

```
| subpart        | quantity |
| wood_fragment  | 140      |
| metal_fragment | 12       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted the answer from the [IBM's recursion example about bill of materials (BOM)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059242.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(part, subpart, quantity) AS (
    SELECT part, subpart, quantity
    FROM widget_recipes
    WHERE part = 'chest'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT parent.part, child.subpart, parent.quantity * child.quantity
    FROM cte parent, widget_recipes child
    WHERE parent.subpart = child.part
  )

SELECT subpart, sum(quantity) as total_quantity
FROM cte
  WHERE subpart LIKE '%_fragment' -- omit if you need intermediate subparts
GROUP BY subpart
ORDER BY total_quantity DESC, subpart;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a question very similar to the example given in the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) for recursive CTEs.  Try using the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(subpart, part, quantity) AS (
    SELECT part, subpart, quantity FROM widget_recipes WHERE part = 'chest'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.part, t2.subpart, t2.quantity
    FROM cte t1
    INNER JOIN widget_recipes t2
        ON t1.subpart = t2.part
)

SELECT part, subpart, quantity
FROM cte;
```

Comment: It is similar and I consulted the Postgres documentation, but I can't find a way to get the results I want. The answer you posted doesn't multiply quantities and results in an infinite loop.